# Is there some notion of work associated with performing a measurement?

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation, povm

Let a measurement be described by POVM elements $M_i$ such that probability $p(i) = Tr[\rho M_i]$ for some state $\rho$. I want to know whether there is some notion of work associated with such measurements.

Comment: This [paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2020-01-13-222/pdf/) seems relevant.